# How to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k^2}$ for different $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

This is quick question, hopefully. How can I evaluate  $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k^2}$? Some power series can easily be reduced to a geometric series, taylor series etc. via term wise integration/differentiation. I want to find an expression for $f(x)$ not involving series, to be able to calculate the exact value for the sum for different $x\in (-1,1)$. I've already shown that the radius of convergence is 1, and the series looks kind of like the regular geometric series. I've tried to do some term wise integration/differentiation, which however turned out to not work very well. Perhaps this is easy, but it has been a while since I was doing these kind of problems.

Cheers!

Comment: It's not easy. Indeed, it's not elementary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function

Comment: ... but of course numerical evaluation is easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}x^{k^{2}} =
-\,{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}x^{k^{2}} =
\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{\vartheta_{3}\left(0,x\right) - 1 \over 2}}$
where $\displaystyle\vartheta_{\nu}$ is a [Jacobi Theta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html).

Answer (score 2):

As Felix Marin pointed out,
your sum is very close to
a Jacobi Theta Function.

There are an
astounding number of identities
for these functions.

For computing it,
this identity
relates small and large
arguments:

If
$g(x)
= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}e^{-k^{2}\pi x} 
$
then
$\dfrac{1+2g(x)}{1+2g(1/x)}
=\dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}
$.

Since
$f(x) 
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k^2}
$,
$f(e^{-\pi x})
=g(x)
$
or
$f(x)
= g(-\ln(x)/\pi)
$.